# Calculating dates by removing Saturdays and Sundays from the week

Tags: apex

I have some issues in calculating the dates. I am working on a task where I need to calculate milestone kickoff date and Deadline date based on a number of days entered by a user. I need to calculate the days by removing the Saturdays and Sundays from the calculations. If the Kickoffdate is Friday, the number of days is 2 then the deadline date should be Tuesday. I wrote a code that will calculate this but it's only working on Indian timezone((GMT+05:30) India Standard Time (Asia/Colombo)) but its throwing wrong dates when I use (GMT-07:00) Mountain Standard Time (America/Phoenix) time zone. How does this matter with times and timezones on salesforce? Below is the sample code of calculations. I tried adding extra minutes but it's still showing wrong dates when I choose the Phoenix time zone.

```
if(milesMap.containsKey(cb.Description_Timeline_Item_1__c)){
     MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Milestone__c mile = milesMap.get(cb.Description_Timeline_Item_1__c);
     Datetime sdate = cb.Project__r.Lease_Execution_Date__c;
     integer iCount = 0;

     while(iCount < 2){

          sdate = sdate.adddays(1);
          system.debug('sdate.format(E) --> '+ sdate.format('E'));

          if (sdate.format('E') != 'Sat' && sdate.format('E') != 'Sun') {
                        iCount = iCount + 1;
          }

      }

     mile.MPM4_BASE__Kickoff__c = Date.valueof(sdate);
     Datetime sdate2 = mile.MPM4_BASE__Kickoff__c;
     integer iCount2 = 0;

     while(iCount2 < cb.Timeline_Item_1__c){
           sdate2 = sdate2.adddays(1);

           if (sdate2.format('E') != 'Sat' && sdate2.format('E') != 'Sun') {
                iCount2 = iCount2 + 1;
           }

     }

     mile.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c = Date.valueof(sdate2);

     milesMap.put(cb.Description_Timeline_Item_1__c, mile);

     system.debug( mile.MPM4_BASE__Kickoff__c + ' - ' + mile.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c);

}
```

Comment: Salesforce stores all date-times in GMT in the DB and local calculations are performed based on user's setup. I'm assuming your dates are off because the date is being interpreted incorrectly within some of the methods you are using. Look into the business hours apex class (it might help): https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm#apex_System_BusinessHours_methods
Otherwise you will have to consider complex scenarios (many weekends in between) and make sure your apex logic computes the correct dates in every step

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, can we add additional hours to GMT to make it MST timezone? Can you help me formatting it?

Comment: Hi, we have posts here in Stackexchange that would solve this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211915/how-to-set-datetime-to-be-a-specific-time-in-a-fixed-timezone
Hope that helps!