# How to convert this string in to date time

Tags: apex

I have to convert the below string into datetime, then i need to assign that datetime which i convert from string into datetime field.

```
                datetime createdGMT = datetime.now();
string createdTZ = createdGMT.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'America/Chicago');
```

Comment: Hello, what you are trying to achieve? parse back to datetime - Datetime.valueOf(createdTZ)? or if the issue is in timezones - ptal https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211915/how-to-set-datetime-to-be-a-specific-time-in-a-fixed-timezone

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert a DateTime into a String if you just want to put it into a DateTime field. You can simply do something like this:

```
myRecord.my_datetime_field__c = Datetime.now();
```

The field will be stored as Datetime and users will see the values in their time zones